# Loading Iframe with fixed height and width into UIWebview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a webpage in server. Its content can be loaded into UIWebView:

```
     NSString* htmlContent = [self getHTMLContentFromUrl:httpUrl];
    
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:content
                       baseURL:nil];
```

The problem is that if webpage has an iframe with specified height and width (applied either through style or attributes), when loaded into the webview, the iframe was not displayed in specified height and width.

In other words, only by scrolling webview it is possible to see the entire content of iframe, but the need is **to limit the height and width of the iframe so that it fits within the webview size**.

Can't the UiWebView realize the iframe height and width? Or is there is another way to achieve the same?